# Parsing Cookies in bash cgi scripts

Tags: bash, cookies, apache2, cgi

I am trying to transfer from less of query strings and more of cookies.  So i need to make a script that parses the cookies from the HTTP_COOKIE request header. The format of the cookies is:

```
{cookiename}={cookievalue} {other-cookies}={other-cookie-value}
```

My options are to either only look for a set {cookiename} and set that to the value...or to scan through the full list of cookies and parse it so the bash variable $cookiename will equal {cookievalue}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming best case scenario, your cookies may already be Bash friendly. In this case you can source the cookie file.

```
. cookies.txt
```

and Bash will save each cookie to a variable. However as many will tell you the file is likely not formatted correctly, perhaps having one or more of these problems

- invalid characters in variable name
- no quotes around values

in which case you would need to add that using `sed` before sourcing the file.

Comment: can you explain a little more...I don't understand what it is that . cooies.txt would do?

Comment: I see what the idea is with the . cookies.txt, but the problem is that I have my cookies being sent to the cgi via the $HTTP_COOKIES variable, and when i do . $HTTP_COOKIES, it   says no file exists

Comment: i'm using a cookie.txt created by curl. but it is invalid, can you give sed example for parsing this file?